# Errors with making a function in swift

Tags: swift

the goal of this function is to receive an array of int and a function. the data with true value will be initialize to the new array which is arrayOfInts.  I'm still new to swift so pls bear with me.

here is the code

```
func Name(a:[Int],op:Int->Bool)->[Int]
{

var array: [Int]

    for i in 0..<a.count
    {
        if even(a[i]) == true
            {
                array[i] = a[i]
            }
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: You haven't added any values to `arrayOfInts`, but you're trying to read values from it.

Comment: You need append your elements

Comment: arrayOfInts is just an empty array. It will get values from a array. i'm still clueless

Comment: how you declare `arrayOfInts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arrayOfInts is not initialised that is what causing the problem.
Initialise it and you can set the array values to zero or whatever is appropriate.

```
var arrayOfInts = [Int](count:a.count, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Comment: thanks, what if i want the size of my arrayofints not dependent to the array?   i tried this code: [0,1,2,3] and it returns [0,2,0,0]. the result that i expected is [0,2]

Comment: You can use any value for the count parameter. I just used the a.count in the example as that is what you are trying to do. If you don't want to use specific value. Just use var arrayOfInts = [Int]() and that would initialise the array with a count of zero or empty.

Comment: @john you should _accept_ this answer (checkmark). It's better than my answer because it goes all the way to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
var arrayOfInts: [Int]
```

to this

```
var arrayOfInts: [Int] = []
```

That will prevent the "used uninitialized" error. But of course you will crash at runtime when you refer to, say, `arrayOfInts[0]` and it doesn't exist!

Comment: `var arrayOfInts = [Int]()`

Comment: I'm not even suggesting your answer is wrong.  I'm just offering an alternative syntax.  By most Swift style guides, the preference is to let the type be inferred.

Comment: @nhgrif Type inference is happening in both cases. It's subtle, but Matt's is actually more interesting because Swift is one of the only languages where type inference occurs on the RHS as well.

Comment: @nhgrif I would write it your way if I were writing my own code, but I am teaching here. I am trying to show the OP what is wrong with the code. The way I'm writing it, the crucial difference — that it needs a _value_ — is clearer.